# Excluding Target Platforms From Eclipse Tycho p2-repository-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho, p2, target-platform

I have a rcp product being built with eclipse tycho and with all different target platform types included in the  portion of my pom.xml it takes about 20 minutes to build the project. I only want to build a target platform for Mac and Linux64 but when I remove the other environments in that configuration section of my pom.xml file I get the following error...

> publishing result: [Included element org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.; Included element org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86_64 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.; Included element org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86_64 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.; Included element org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.; Included element org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_64 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.; Included element org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.; Included element org.eclipse.ui.win32 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determined >

I get the error message, when I don't want to build for windows its still trying to find that plugin for win32 SWT because I imagine tycho does not add it to the target platform it constructs? If I remove the target platform specific dependencies from my .product file where would I add them and how would I go about getting this to work when only targeting specific target platforms in tycho. Thanks for any help! - Duncan Krebs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. The problem was I had platform specific dependencies of plugins like org.eclipse.swt in my .product file, so when trying to build with Tycho it was looking for these plugins and they were not there because i did not include the target environments for these platforms in my pom.xml After removing any plugin that ended with a platform specific convention like win_32 and just keeping the generic plugins like org.eclipse.swt as dependencies I was able to build without errors and only target the platforms I'm interested it. Hope this helps someone along the way.